# How to prove math discrete expression in right way?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have such expression

$$ \{A\} \subseteq P(B) \to P(A) \subseteq P(B) $$

As far as I understand I have to convert expression left part to make it fit right one.

But I don't see any associations with these two parts...

Comment: You know that $A$ is in $P(B)$ from the left side of the conditional.  What other sets *must* be in $P(B)$?  What other sets are in $P(A)$?  Do you see now that the right side of the conditional must also be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\{A\} \subseteq P(B)$ then $A \in P(B)$ so $A \subseteq B$

Thus every subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$ which tells us that $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$

Answer (score 1):

$\{A\} \subseteq \mathcal P(B)$ implies $A \in \mathcal P(B)$. Therefore $A$ is a subset of $B$. Therefore any subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$ which is the conclusion where are looking for.